# Would this be considered a fractal?

Tags: recursion, fractals

[image]

I was wondering if this would be considered a fractal or just a recursive shape. It seems like it is to me, but our lab says "However, it is not just enough that the shape was generated by some recursive process, because there are shapes you could generate recursively which are not fractals," but it also explains more. To me, it seems like it is, but I just wanted to make sure.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question properly belongs on the mathematics stack exchange site, I think.

Comment: If a spiral is a fractal, so is this one

Comment: A spiral is not a fractal.

Comment: Then this one isn't either.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not a fractal, because it doesn't demonstrate self-similarity. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fractal.html

Comment: Thank you, also upon further research, it needs some specific level of detail. If it didn't then a line would technically be a fractal.

Comment: @Jordan hence Rahul's much-more-comprehensive answer (which was for some bizarre reason downvoted).

Answer (score 2):

A fractal has recursive properties, but not all recursive figures are fractals.

Here's what my rule of thumb is to decide whether a shape is a fractal or not:

1. Zoom into the object by a factor of X (say).
2. Count how many copies of the original object are in the zoomed-in version, let's call it N.
3. The dimension of the object is the logarithm of N, to the base X.

Eg: Zoom into a square by a factor of 2, you'll have 4 copies of the square that "fit inside" the larger square. Since log 4 (base 2) is 2, hence this is a 2D object.

Look at the [Koch curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake):
[image]
Zooming in 3x will give you 4 copies of the original curve, hence its "dimension" is log 4 (base 3), which is a number between 1 and 2... a *fractional* dimension, (hence the name fractal).

Applying this rule to your recursive figure, if you zoom in 2x, you will still see the original figure (N = 1). Its dimension works out to be log 1 (base 2), which is zero.

Since zero is not a fraction, therefore your figure is not a fractal.

Comment: I disagree with your measurement of that figure's dimension. You can't just assign zero to just anything that is invariant under scaling. Otherwise, you'd assign zero dimensions to the infinite plane. Also note space-filling curves have a fractal dimension of exactly two, and they are hardly _not fractal_.

Comment: The correct definition of Hausdorff dimension measures the limit of  [log(the number of balls needed to cover the shape)]/[log(the size of the balls)]. This coincides with the rule you're using when it comes to fractals that are composed of themselves, but it breaks down for anything of infinite size. Then you'd use the definition that the dimension of an infinite set is the same as that of any compact subset of thereof, maximised over all such subsets. Bonus points if every neighborhood of every point has that dimension.

Comment: Apart from the last two paragraphs, your usage of the [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) (more exactly, of the [box-counting dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) where the limit converges)

Comment: it# s not of fractal because it can be coded with a simple loop without recursion.